# Populate model dropdown onchange of brandnames dropdown via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

view like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Brand Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control" id="brand_mod" name="brand_name" required>
                    <option value="" selected disabled="disabled">Select Brand Here</option>
                    <?php foreach($b->result() as $row) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"> <?php echo $row->brand_name; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Model</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select name="model_number" class="form-control" id="models">
                    <option value="">--Select model --</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

in brand name dropdown brand names are properly visible below that there is my model name dropdown... i want when i click on any brand name its models get displayed on model dropdown
then my ajax call is

```
<script>
    $('#brand_mod').change(function(){  

    var bbb = $('#brand_mod').val();
    //alert(bbb);

     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("<?php echo base_url(); ?>User/get_models", "Application")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { brand_id : $('#brand_mod').val() },

            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) 
            { 
                alert(data);
                alert('Success'); 
                return false;
            },
            error:function()
            {
                alert('error');
                return false;
            }

        });
    });


</script>
```

then my controller is like this to which ajax call is made

```
public function get_models(){


    $id = $this->input->post('brand_id');
    $this->load->model("user/User_model");
    $result1 = $this->User_model->all_models($id);
    //$data = array();
     '<option value=""></option>'
    foreach($result1 as $row)
    {
     '<option value="'.$row->id'">'.$row->model_name'</option>'
    }
}
```

and my model is

```
public function all_models($id)
{
    $this->db->where('brand_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('wc_models');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

but i am getting error alert.... something is wrong with code... i have tried my best... please help...

Comment: `url: '@Url.Action("<?php echo base_url(); ?>User/get_models", "Application")'` it seems incorrect (i am notsure because i am not a codigintor expert). Also one extra `});` in your ajax code is there.

Comment: sorry i am not very much aware of codegintor

Comment: please chenage `data: { brand_id : $('#brand_mod').val() },` to `data: { 'brand_id' : $('#brand_mod').val() },` and check once. that's also incorrect

Comment: still not working!!!!